# 1D or 2D array, what's faster?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm in need of representing a 2D field (axes x, y) and I face a problem: Should I use an 1D array or a 2D array?

I can imagine, that recalculating indices for 1D arrays (y + x*n) could be slower than using 2D array (x, y) but I could image that 1D could be in CPU cache..

I did some googling, but only found pages regarding static array (and stating that 1D and 2D are basically the same). But my arrays must me dynamic.

So, what's

1. faster,
2. smaller (RAM)

dynamic 1D arrays or dynamic 2D arrays?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference as your 2D array is stored in memory as 1D so whenever you call `arr[x][y]` internally it still computes `(&arr[0][0])[x * dim + y]`

Comment: @juan Technically true but OP is probably speaking of a dynamic array (i.e. `T**`) not a real array. As such, it’s not contiguous any more.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that wouldn't be a 2D array then, would it :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza In common usage it’s absolutely a 2D array. In fact, unless somebody explicitly talks about static lengths, I always assume dynamic arrays and I’m almost always right. Additionally, OP **explicitly** mentions that he needs dynamic arrays.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right, I totally missed the *dynamic* part of the question.

Comment: Whatever indexing method you use, like `arr[n*i + j]` or `arr[i][j]`, the cost of indexing will be vastly overshadowed by any cache delays.  Spend your effort on minimizing cache delays.

Comment: A concise expert advice for real world numerics: http://www.fftw.org/doc/Dynamic-Arrays-in-C_002dThe-Wrong-Way.html#Dynamic-Arrays-in-C_002dThe-Wrong-Way. It even gives a workaround to have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Only *rule* that I can confidently say that will always hold true is "Measure the two approaches and see which one is faster for you".  What is *likely* to be faster is the approach where you make a single contiguous allocation with the equivalent index computed from two indices.

Comment: @Paladin - You should use a 2D dynamic array (vector). Not because it's faster, but because it's a better design.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

#### tl;dr : You should probably use a one-dimensional approach.

*Note: One cannot dig into detail affecting performance when comparing dynamic 1d or dynamic 2d storage patterns without filling books since the performance of code is dependent one a very large number of parameters. Profile if possible.*

#### 1. What's faster?

For dense matrices the 1D approach is likely to be faster since it offers better memory locality and less allocation and deallocation overhead.

#### 2. What's smaller?

Dynamic-1D consumes less memory than the 2D approach. The latter also requires more allocations.

### Remarks

I laid out a pretty long answer beneath with several reasons but I want to make some remarks on your assumptions first.

> I can imagine, that recalculating indices for 1D arrays (y + x*n) could be slower than using 2D array (x, y)

Let's compare these two functions:

```
int get_2d (int **p, int r, int c) { return p[r][c]; }
int get_1d (int *p, int r, int c)  { return p[c + C*r]; }
```

The (non-inlined) assembly generated by Visual Studio 2015 RC for those functions (with optimizations turned on) is:

```
?get_1d@@YAHPAHII@Z PROC
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, DWORD PTR _c$[ebp]
lea eax, DWORD PTR [eax+edx*4]
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ecx+eax*4]
pop ebp
ret 0

?get_2d@@YAHPAPAHII@Z PROC
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [ecx+edx*4]
mov eax, DWORD PTR _c$[ebp]
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ecx+eax*4]
pop ebp
ret 0
```

The difference is `mov` (2d) vs. `lea` (1d). 
The former has a latency of 3 cycles and a a maximum throughput of 2 per cycle while the latter has a latency of 2 cycles and a maximum throughput of 3 per cycle. (According to [Instruction tables - Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf.)
Since the differences are minor, I think there should not be a big performance difference arising from index recalculation. I expect it to be very unlikely to identify this difference itself to be the bottleneck in any program.

This brings us to the next (and more interesting) point:

> ... but I could image that 1D could be in CPU cache ...

True, but 2d could be in CPU cache, too. See *The Downsides: Memory locality* for an explanation why 1d is still better.

## The long answer, or why dynamic 2 dimensional data storage (pointer-to-pointer or vector-of-vector) is "bad" for *simple* / small matrices.

*Note: This is about dynamic arrays/allocation schemes [malloc/new/vector etc.]. A static 2d array is a contiguous block of memory and therefore not subject to the downsides I'm going to present here.*

### The Problem

To be able to understand why a dynamic array of dynamic arrays or a vector of vectors is most likely not the data storage pattern of choice, you are required to understand the memory layout of such structures.

### Example case using pointer to pointer syntax

```
int main (void)
{
    // allocate memory for 4x4 integers; quick & dirty
    int ** p = new int*[4];
    for (size_t i=0; i<4; ++i) p[i] = new int[4]; 

    // do some stuff here, using p[x][y] 

    // deallocate memory
    for (size_t i=0; i<4; ++i) delete[] p[i];
    delete[] p;
}
```

### The downsides

#### Memory locality

For this “matrix” you allocate one block of four pointers and four blocks of four integers. *All of the allocations are unrelated* and can therefore result in an arbitrary memory position.

The following image will give you an idea of how the memory may look like.

For the *real 2d case*:

- The violet square is the memory position occupied by `p` itself.
- The green squares assemble the memory region `p` points to (4 x `int*`).
- The 4 regions of 4 contiguous blue squares are the ones pointed to by each `int*` of the green region

For the *2d mapped on 1d case*:

- The green square is the only required pointer `int *`
- The blue squares ensemble the memory region for all matrix elements (16 x `int`).

[image: Real 2d vs mapped 2d memory layout]

This means that (when using the left layout) you will probably observe worse performance than for a contiguous storage pattern (as seen on the right), due to caching for instance.

Let's say a cache line is "the amount of data transfered into the cache at once" and let's imagine a program accessing the whole matrix one element after another.

If you have a properly aligned 4 times 4 matrix of 32 bit values, a processor with a 64 byte cache line (typical value) is able to "one-shot" the data (4*4*4 = 64 bytes).
If you start processing and the data isn't already in the cache you'll face a cache miss and the data will be fetched from main memory. This load can fetch the whole matrix at once since it fits into a cache line, if and only if it is contiguously stored (and properly aligned).
There will probably not be any more misses while processing that data.

In case of a dynamic, "real two-dimensional" system with unrelated locations of each row/column, the processor needs to load every memory location seperately.
Eventhough only 64 bytes are required, loading 4 cache lines for 4 unrelated memory positions would -in a worst case scenario- actually transfer 256 bytes and waste 75% throughput bandwidth.
If you process the data using the 2d-scheme you'll again (if not already cached) face a cache miss on the first element.
But now, only the first row/colum will be in the cache after the first load from main memory because all other rows are located somewhere else in memory and not adjacent to the first one.
As soon as you reach a new row/column there will again be a cache miss and the next load from main memory is performed.

Long story short: The 2d pattern has a higher chance of cache misses with the 1d scheme offering better potential for performance due to locality of the data.

#### Frequent Allocation / Deallocation

- As many as `N + 1` (4 + 1 = 5) allocations (using either new, malloc, allocator::allocate or whatever) are necessary to create the desired NxM (4×4) matrix.
- The same number of proper, respective deallocation operations must be applied as well.

Therefore, it is more costly to create/copy such matrices in contrast to a single allocation scheme.

*This is getting even worse with a growing number of rows.*

#### Memory consumption overhead

*I'll asumme a size of 32 bits for int and 32 bits for pointers. (Note: System dependency.)*

Let's remember: We want to store a 4×4 int matrix which means 64 bytes.

For a NxM matrix, stored with the presented pointer-to-pointer scheme we consume

- `N*M*sizeof(int)` [the actual blue data] +
- `N*sizeof(int*)` [the green pointers] +
- `sizeof(int**)` [the violet variable p] bytes.

That makes `4*4*4 + 4*4 + 4 = 84` bytes in case of the present example and it gets even worse when using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.
It will require `N * M * sizeof(int)` + `N * sizeof(vector<int>)` + `sizeof(vector<vector<int>>)` bytes, that is `4*4*4 + 4*16 + 16 = 144` bytes in total, intead of 64 bytes for 4 x 4 int.

In addition -depending on the used allocator- each single allocation may well (and most likely will) have another 16 bytes of memory overhead. (Some “Infobytes” which store the number of allocated bytes for the purpose of proper deallocation.)

This means the worst case is:

> `N*(16+M*sizeof(int)) + 16+N*sizeof(int*) + sizeof(int**)`
>   `= 4*(16+4*4) + 16+4*4 + 4 = 164 bytes ! _Overhead: 156%_`

*The share of the overhead will reduce as the size of the matrix grows but will still be present.*

#### Risk of memory leaks

The bunch of allocations requires an appropriate exception handling in order to avoid memory leaks if one of the allocations will fail!
You’ll need to keep track of allocated memory blocks and you must not forget them when deallocating the memory.

If `new` runs of of memory and the next row cannot be allocated (especially likely when the matrix is very large), a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown by `new`.

***Example:***

In the above mentioned new/delete example, we'll face some more code if we want to avoid leaks in case of `bad_alloc` exceptions.

```
  // allocate memory for 4x4 integers; quick & dirty
  size_t const N = 4;
  // we don't need try for this allocation
  // if it fails there is no leak
  int ** p = new int*[N];
  size_t allocs(0U);
  try 
  { // try block doing further allocations
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) 
    {
      p[i] = new int[4]; // allocate
      ++allocs; // advance counter if no exception occured
    }
  }
  catch (std::bad_alloc & be)
  { // if an exception occurs we need to free out memory
    for (size_t i=0; i<allocs; ++i) delete[] p[i]; // free all alloced p[i]s
    delete[] p; // free p
    throw; // rethrow bad_alloc
  }
  /*
     do some stuff here, using p[x][y] 
  */
  // deallocate memory accoding to the number of allocations
  for (size_t i=0; i<allocs; ++i) delete[] p[i];
  delete[] p;
```

### Summary

There are cases where "real 2d" memory layouts fit and make sense (i.e. if the number of columns per row is not constant) but in the most simple and common 2D data storage cases they just bloat the complexity of your code and reduce the performance and memory efficiency of your program.

## Alternative

You should use a contiguous block of memory and map your rows onto that block.

The "C++ way" of doing it is probably to write a class that manages your memory while considering important things like

- [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)
- [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)
- [C++ concept: Container (on cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container)

### Example

To provide an idea of how such a class may look like, here's a simple example with some basic features:

- 2d-size-constructible
- 2d-resizable
- `operator(size_t, size_t)` for 2d- row major element access
- `at(size_t, size_t)` for checked 2d-row major element access
- Fulfills Concept requirements for *Container*

Source:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

namespace matrices
{

  template<class T>
  class simple
  {
  public:
    // misc types
    using data_type  = std::vector<T>;
    using value_type = typename std::vector<T>::value_type;
    using size_type  = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;
    // ref
    using reference       = typename std::vector<T>::reference;
    using const_reference = typename std::vector<T>::const_reference;
    // iter
    using iterator       = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
    using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
    // reverse iter
    using reverse_iterator       = typename std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator;

    // empty construction
    simple() = default;

    // default-insert rows*cols values
    simple(size_type rows, size_type cols)
      : m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols), m_data(rows*cols)
    {}

    // copy initialized matrix rows*cols
    simple(size_type rows, size_type cols, const_reference val)
      : m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols), m_data(rows*cols, val)
    {}

    // 1d-iterators

    iterator begin() { return m_data.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return m_data.end(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return m_data.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return m_data.end(); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return m_data.cbegin(); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return m_data.cend(); }
    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return m_data.rbegin(); }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return m_data.rend(); }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return m_data.rbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return m_data.rend(); }
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return m_data.crbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return m_data.crend(); }

    // element access (row major indexation)
    reference operator() (size_type const row,
      size_type const column)
    {
      return m_data[m_cols*row + column];
    }
    const_reference operator() (size_type const row,
      size_type const column) const
    {
      return m_data[m_cols*row + column];
    }
    reference at() (size_type const row, size_type const column)
    {
      return m_data.at(m_cols*row + column);
    }
    const_reference at() (size_type const row, size_type const column) const
    {
      return m_data.at(m_cols*row + column);
    }

    // resizing
    void resize(size_type new_rows, size_type new_cols)
    {
      // new matrix new_rows times new_cols
      simple tmp(new_rows, new_cols);
      // select smaller row and col size
      auto mc = std::min(m_cols, new_cols);
      auto mr = std::min(m_rows, new_rows);
      for (size_type i(0U); i < mr; ++i)
      {
        // iterators to begin of rows
        auto row = begin() + i*m_cols;
        auto tmp_row = tmp.begin() + i*new_cols;
        // move mc elements to tmp
        std::move(row, row + mc, tmp_row);
      }
      // move assignment to this
      *this = std::move(tmp);
    }

    // size and capacity
    size_type size() const { return m_data.size(); }
    size_type max_size() const { return m_data.max_size(); }
    bool empty() const { return m_data.empty(); }
    // dimensionality
    size_type rows() const { return m_rows; }
    size_type cols() const { return m_cols; }
    // data swapping
    void swap(simple &rhs)
    {
      using std::swap;
      m_data.swap(rhs.m_data);
      swap(m_rows, rhs.m_rows);
      swap(m_cols, rhs.m_cols);
    }
  private:
    // content
    size_type m_rows{ 0u };
    size_type m_cols{ 0u };
    data_type m_data{};
  };
  template<class T>
  void swap(simple<T> & lhs, simple<T> & rhs)
  {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
  }
  template<class T>
  bool operator== (simple<T> const &a, simple<T> const &b)
  {
    if (a.rows() != b.rows() || a.cols() != b.cols())
    {
      return false;
    }
    return std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
  }
  template<class T>
  bool operator!= (simple<T> const &a, simple<T> const &b)
  {
    return !(a == b);
  }

}
```

*Note several things here:*

- `T` needs to fulfill the requirements of the used `std::vector` member functions
- `operator()` doesn't do any "of of range" checks
- No need to manage data on your own
- No destructor, copy constructor or assignment operators required

So you don't have to bother about proper memory handling for each application but only once for the class you write.

## Restrictions

There may be cases where a dynamic "real" two dimensional structure is favourable. This is for instance the case if

- the matrix is very large and sparse (if any of the rows do not even need to be allocated but can be handled using a nullptr) or if
- the rows do not have the same number of columns (that is if you don't have a matrix at all but another two-dimensional construct).

Comment: It’s a nice answer but why do yo insist on using (and discussing at all) raw pointers in your example? There’s no reason to, in modern C++. Just use `std::vector` and be done with it.

Comment: I have 2 main reasons for using the pointer example. First of all it has a prdictable memory layout (the standard has no guarantee how the vector itself looks like) and the second point is that most of the "naive approaches" I see here on SO use pointers.

Comment: I recently added an answer regarding the comon layout std::vector and how it is laid out in memory. Perhaps this is of interest in relation to this question. [c++ Vector, what happens whenever it expands/reallocate on stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299951/c-vector-what-happens-whenever-it-expands-reallocate-on-stack/17302443#17302443)

Comment: There's another reason why doing the "2D dynamic Array" thing is bad, but that's more likely to bite you only on large-sized ones: `new` can `throw` when it runs out of memory. Since the "dynamic alloc" this style requires at least _two_ calls to `new` (the first one for the `T*[N]` array, and the second one for the `T[N*M]`), so you must also `try { } catch {}` around each or you would leak memory if the 1st one succeeds and the 2nd one throws. The real culprit is that C++/STL never bothered with a standard `matrix` class. If Fortran got anything right over C/C++, then that's the one ...

Comment: @FrankH That's what I mean by "_The bunch of allocations requires an appropriate exception handling to avoid memory leaks if one of the allocations will fail!_" @**Risk of memory leaks** but I think I'll have a review to advance on that a little further.

Comment: Contiguous memory also allows the compiler to auto-vectorize better with SIMD.  For example, [this code got a **50x speedup** by using a flat array instead of pointers-to-pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232454/faster-way-to-do-multi-dimensional-matrix-addition).  (It was nearly worst-case: a 3D matrix of pointers to pointers to rows of only 4 `double`s, and looping in the wrong order for locality if things had been allocated mostly contiguously.)  The OP hasn't reported the [speedup for the new bottleneck](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37254001/224132), but it should be significant

Comment: Isn't there a few typos here : `reference at() (size_type const row, size_type const column)
    {
      return m_data.at(m_cols*row + column);
    }
    at operator() (size_type const row, size_type const column) const
    {
      return m_data.at(m_cols*row + column);
    }` ? Shouldn't it be changed to `reference at(size_type const row, size_type const column)` and `const_reference at(size_type const row, size_type const column) const` ?

Comment: @beesleep: Yeah .. that happens when you copy and paste `operator()` and half heartedly rename it into `at` ;)

Comment: Your assembly example is misleading. It assumes `C==4`, for larger or variable `C` it will need a `mul` or at least extra `shl`. It probably still doesn't change the big picture.

Answer (score 24):

**Unless** you are talking about static arrays, **1D is faster**.

Here’s the memory layout of a 1D array (`std::vector<T>`):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And here’s the same for a dynamic 2D array (`std::vector<std::vector<T>>`):

```
+---+---+---+
| * | * | * |
+-|-+-|-+-|-+
  |   |   V
  |   | +---+---+---+
  |   | |   |   |   |
  |   | +---+---+---+
  |   V
  | +---+---+---+
  | |   |   |   |
  | +---+---+---+
  V
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Clearly the 2D case loses the cache locality and uses more memory. It also introduces an extra indirection (and thus an extra pointer to follow) but the first array has the overhead of calculating the indices so these even out more or less.

Comment: Good answer. I also thought about cache misses on dynamical 2d array

Answer (score 12):

## **1D and 2D Static Arrays**

- **Size:** Both will require the same amount of memory.
- **Speed:** You can assume that there will be no speed difference because the memory for both of these arrays should be contiguous (The
  whole 2D array should appear as one chunk in memory rather than a
  bunch of chunks spread across memory). (This could be compiler
  dependent however.)

## **1D and 2D Dynamic Arrays**

- **Size:** The 2D array will require a tiny bit more memory than the 1D array because of the pointers needed in the 2D array to point to the set of allocated 1D arrays. (This tiny bit is only tiny when we're talking about really big arrays. For small arrays, the tiny bit could be pretty big relatively speaking.)
- **Speed:** The 1D array may be faster than the 2D array because the memory for the 2D array would not be contiguous, so cache misses would become a problem.

---

Use what works and seems most logical, and if you face speed problems, then refactor.

Comment: "There is no speed difference." That really depends on how compiler calculates offsets for 2D arrays.

Comment: On speed, it also depends on how you're using the array. Calculating the offset for randomly-accessed elements is the same, but if you want to iterate all elements, it's easy with a one-dimensional array to just iterate linearly and not bother with nested loops or with multiplying multidimensional coordinates into memory offsets.

Comment: But how about a `static std::vector<T>` is it a static or dynamic? Sorry I don't have the capability to distinguish between those.

Comment: the dynamic "2D array" is an array of pointers pointing to other arrays. So it requires more space than a 1D array.

Comment: Oh hey, that's right. Thank you for making that correction. @mr5 An std::vector<T> will behave like a dynamic 1D array because it was programmed that way. (When we say `static`, we are not referring to the `static` keyword per se)

Comment: As I pointed out a 4x4 `vector<vector<int>>` will (system dependantly) require 164 bytes, where 100 bytes are overhead. I wouldn't call that "a tiny bit" (it is a factor > 2.5), especially if you need to handle many of those or if you need to copy them very often. (It's of course loosing significance with a growing number of columns.)

Comment: @Pixelchemist That's true, and I didn't mention it because I expect his arrays to be pretty big if he's going to worry about speed. :P (Guess it would be better to state so explicitly though)

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers all only compare 1-D arrays against arrays of pointers.

In C (but not C++) there is a third option; you can have a contiguous 2-D array that is dynamically allocated and has runtime dimensions:

```
int (*p)[num_columns] = malloc(num_rows * sizeof *p);
```

and this is accessed like `p[row_index][col_index]`.

I would expect this to have very similar performance to the 1-D array case,  but it gives you nicer syntax for accessing the cells.

In C++ you can achieve something similar by defining a class which maintains a 1-D array internally, but can expose it via 2-D array access syntax using overloaded operators. Again I would expect that to have similar or identical performance to the plain 1-D array.

Comment: That sounds weird to be honest, I always thought that almost any valid C is valid C++.. g++ 4.8.3 takes this code http://pastebin.com/Te2n1XhZ...

Comment: @Paladin C and C++ are different languages each has some features the other doesn't, and some of the common features are implemented differently. Try invoking g++ in standard mode and you will get a diagnostic,  by default it has some extensions enabled.

Comment: @M.M *In C (but not C++) there is a third option* Why only in C? In C++ you can easily do `int (*p)[num_cols] = new int[num_rows][num_cols]; delete[] p;`.

Comment: @vsoftco in your C++ code `num_cols` must be a constant expression, but in my code it can be determined at runtime

Comment: @M.M Ohh I see, thanks! Yes indeed, the lhs is a pointer to a VLA in C, good point!

Answer (score 4):

Another difference of 1D and 2D arrays appears in memory allocation. We cannot be sure that members of 2D array be sequental.

Comment: Yes. And this can have a serious impact where the array in question is in that 1% of performance-critical code.

Comment: Isn't it possible to guarantee contiguous memory by allocating a large block with malloc and then taking a contiguous part of that block for a 2d array? I believe I have heard this being used in games etc.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how your 2D array is implemented.

consider the code below:

```
int a[200], b[10][20], *c[10], *d[10];
for (ii = 0; ii < 10; ++ii)
{
   c[ii] = &b[ii][0];
   d[ii] = (int*) malloc(20 * sizeof(int));    // The cast for C++ only.
}
```

There are 3 implementations here: b, c and d

There won't be a lot of difference accessing `b[x][y]` or `a[x*20 + y]`, since one is you doing the computation and the other is the compiler doing it for you.  `c[x][y]` and `d[x][y]` are slower, because the machine has to find the address that `c[x]` points to and then access the yth element from there.  It is not one straight computation.  On some machines (eg AS400 which has 36 byte (not bit) pointers), pointer access is extremely slow.  It all depends on the architecture in use.  On x86 type architectures, a and b are the same speed, c and d are slower than b.

Answer (score 0):

I love the thorough answer provided by [Pixelchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951423/pixelchemist). A simpler version of this solution may be as follows. First, declare the dimensions:

```
constexpr int M = 16; // rows
constexpr int N = 16; // columns
constexpr int P = 16; // planes
```

Next, create an alias and, get and set methods:

```
template<typename T>
using Vector = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T>
inline T& set_elem(vector<T>& m_, size_t i_, size_t j_, size_t k_)
{
    // check indexes here...
    return m_[i_*N*P + j_*P + k_];
}

template<typename T>
inline const T& get_elem(const vector<T>& m_, size_t i_, size_t j_, size_t k_)
{
    // check indexes here...
    return m_[i_*N*P + j_*P + k_];
}
```

Finally, a vector may be created and indexed as follows:

```
Vector array3d(M*N*P, 0);            // create 3-d array containing M*N*P zero ints
set_elem(array3d, 0, 0, 1) = 5;      // array3d[0][0][1] = 5
auto n = get_elem(array3d, 0, 0, 1); // n = 5
```

Defining the vector size at initialization provides [optimal performance](https://lemire.me/blog/2012/06/20/do-not-waste-time-with-stl-vectors/). This solution is modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305621/problems-using-3-dimensional-vector). The functions may be overloaded to support varying dimensions with a single vector. The downside of this solution is that the M, N, P parameters are implicitly passed to the get and set functions. This can be resolved by implementing the solution within a class, as done by [Pixelchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951423/pixelchemist).