# C++ How do I use a variable for the size of the pointer when creating a pointer?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers

I get the ERROR:EXPRESSION MUST HAVE A CONSTANT VALUE.  Is there a way to actually use variables since my rows can possibly change with every file that is going to be read.

```
Image readFile(string fileName) {
ifstream file;
file.open(fileName);
int row;
int column;
Image image(0, 0);
if(file.is_open()){

        file >> row;
        file >> column;

}
int **row[row]; // error right here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  ERROR:EXPRESSION MUST HAVE A CONSTANT VALUE
file.close();
image(row, column);
return image(row, column);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allocate the memory dynamically, Replace the line with the following line

```
int **row = new int*[rowCount];
```

Comment: You also need to make sure that you use 'delete' at some point to dispose the memory.

Comment: This is exceptionally bad advice, given that `std::vector` exists (and takes care of the `delete`, even in the face of an exception).

Comment: Also, it should have been `delete[]` if you ignore the better alternative of `std::vector` (See how easy it is to make mistakes with raw pointers?)

Answer (score 4):

If I may give you a piece of advice: Do not use raw memory in this situation. Stick to RAII and use a container for 2d data.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
```

If you're somehow concerned about performance have a look at this answer, on why to use contiguous storage instead: [Why is dynamic 2 dimensional data storage (pointer-to-pointer or vector-of-vector) "bad" for simple 2d storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster/17260533#17260533).

Manual raw memory handling is very likely to result in errors like memory leaks, undefined bahaviour etc.

Comment: Indeed; at the very least, a smart pointer would solve the issue of how to deallocate the chunk of memory.