# How to represent 2D matrix in c++

Tags: c++

Is it faster to represent at 2D matrix as an array of arrays, or as a 1D array with a function that converts co-ordinates to the corrisponding array index?

Comment: Benchmark and find out.

Comment: I think that this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster

Comment: If the arrays are dynamically allocated, probably the latter.

Comment: Two dimensional array!!!

Answer (score 4):

You could make a 1D array and an array of row pointers. Then you get the best of both worlds: a convenient interface with good memory locality and predictable accesses.

```
int *  matrix1d = new int [rows * cols];
int ** matrix2d = new int * [rows];
for (size_t i = 0; i != rows; ++i)
    matrix2d[i] = &matrix1d[i * cols];

int v1 = matrix1d[r * cols + c];
int v2 = matrix2d[r][c];
```

Comment: Also you can do some cool tricks, like constant-time row swaps (very useful for some matrix reduction algorithms)

Comment: Better protect `new` with smart pointers like `vector<int>` or `unique_ptr<int[]>` to avoid memory leaks. Maybe also stuff the whole code into a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use `std::vector` because it's dynamic in nature and easy to use.

```
int row;
int col;
std::vector< std::vector<int> > two_d_matrix( row, std::vector<int>(col));
```

Note if you are using `std::vector` don't forget to add `#include<vector>`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, if you're going to be traversing this thing often, you've just thrown locality of data out the window.

Answer (score 0):

2D array is more convenient, for example

```
const int rows = 100;
const int cols = 100;
int arr[rows][cols];
```

You refer the array elements as `arr[i][j]` where `0 <= i < rows`and `0 <= j < cols`

Comment: More convenient, until the day when you actually need the size chosen at runtime.  Then it falls flat.

Answer (score 0):

`const int  row = 256;
const int  col = 256;
vector<vector<int> >    matrix2D(row, (col,0));`
/*By this we can say that we have a 2D matrix that is 256*256，and all the elements are 0. */