# Error during allocating memory for double values

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I got a problem in my code by allocating a two-dimensional array for double values.
So first the code I use:

```
double** matrix;
double ncolumn=2;
double nrow;

for (size_t i=0; i<nSlices; ++i) {
    const std::vector<LineSegment> &lss = slicesWithLineSegments[i];
    //I use 
    nrow = lss.size();//Returns the numbers ob Row;
    matrix = malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*));

    for (size_t j=0; j<nrow; ++j) 
    {
        matrix[j] = malloc(ncolumn * sizeof(double));
    }
}
```

Since I have a number of segments, and each segment has a different number of lines, I have to edit the array for each segment. That's why i use the for-loop with nSlices.

But in the two lines with the malloc commands I get a error from visual studio. Here's the error-message:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'double *'
>     error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'double *'
>     IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double **"
>     IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double *"

I also tried to use calloc, but I also got this error messages. I also had a look on google, and just found the code in the way I did it. But the errors still remain.

Comment: you have to cast `(double *) malloc( ... ) ` in c++ or to use  ̀new double*`

Comment: So do I write: matrix = (double* ) malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*)); and matrix[j] = (double *) malloc(ncolumn * sizeof(double));

Comment: Please! This is C++. Use `new[]` and `delete[]`, or better yet, `vector<double>`.

Comment: @Roddy I'm using now the new[] command and now I'm able to allocate the memory. To free the memory do I have to use the reverse path for the array. So first the delete[] command in a for-loop, than delet[] for the array?

Comment: @user3794592 Yes. (but `std::vector` would save you the trouble of deleting)

Answer (score 1):

malloc returns a (void*) pointer, you should cast the return to (double**) and (double*)

```
matrix = (double**)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*));

matrix[j] = (double*)malloc(ncolumn * sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error messages plainly tell you what's going on: `malloc` returns `void*` which is neither `double**`, nor `double*`. Either cast the result:

```
matrix = (double**)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*));
// ...
matrix[j] = (double*)malloc(ncolumn * sizeof(double));
```

or refactor to `std::vector<double>` (note: *not `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` if a dense matrix is required*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster/17260533#17260533)) which is easier and safer.

Answer (score 0):

malloc return void *. Try (double *) before malloc or use operator new