# Segmentation fault in matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault

I've tried to create a matrix in C and have some input value, but I don't know why it throws me a "segmentation error". This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int j;
    int **a;
    a = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      a[i] = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        scanf("%d", (a[i][j]));
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `scanf("%d", &(a[i][j]));`

Comment: If you compile with gcc, it warns you you're using scanf wrong, resolving gcc warning often solve a lot of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your allocation for `a` should be

`a=malloc(5*sizeof(int*));`

Note well the pointer type in the `sizof`. On some systems (Windows desktops in the early 2000s) an `int` just happened to be the same size as an `int*`, but you **must not** assume that.

2. `scanf` takes a *pointer* as the parameter: the clearest way to write this is `scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);`
3. Don't forget to `free` the memory once you're all done.

Finally, I die a little inside every time I see a matrix modelled like this. Granted, it allows you to use the `[][]` notation, but normally it's better to model it as a contiguous memory block and use the idiom `i * columns + j` to access the element at `(i, j)`.

Comment: thanks to help, can you do me a example of use the idiom    i * columns+j?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster

Comment: `i * columns + j` isn't necessary since 1999. One can use a pointer to a VLA and thereby get the convenient `[][]` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Given the answer by @Bathsheba, this is what your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  int (*a)[4] = malloc( sizeof(int[5][4]) );

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
  }

  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is the "ace" answer, but I don't have enough confidence to use it, especially when you have to consider decay to pointers.

Comment: @Bathsheba Array pointers don't decay. When passing this array pointer to a function, you would simply declare the function as `void func (size_t x, size_t y, int array[x][y])`. Where `int array[x][y]` will get adjusted by the compiler ("decay") into a pointer to the first element: `int (*array)[y]`. Which is exactly what we have in the caller.

Comment: That's helpful. In fact much of this is above my pay grade. Do feel free to take facets from my answer and incorporate it into this one.

Comment: @Bathsheba Nah, your answer is fine, I just couldn't stand by watching you die inside :)