# How do I pass a truly immutable 2D array to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I have this function:

```
void foo(const double *const *matrix, unsigned num_rows, unsigned num_columns){
    //matrix[0][0] = 5; // ERROR: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) delete matrix[i];
    delete matrix;
}
```

...wherein the function cannot change the values at any given index in the matrix, *yet it is still able to delete the matrix or any of its rows*. Is there a way to pass in a 2D matrix and guarantee that it will not be altered in any way?

Edit: it doesn't look like there's a way to do this, so I'll probably switch to using vectors.

Comment: I'd start out to dump raw arrays for doing such, but using a `std::array<std::array<double,num_rows>,num_cols>` or a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`

Comment: See '[1D or 2D array, what's faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster)' about why you most likely do not want to have 2 dimensional dynamic arrays of arrays or `vector<vector<T>>` for (dense) matrices anyway. My answer has a small matrix example class. (You can of course just have `vector<T>` and handle the mapping for yourself.)

Comment: Cool tip, Pixelchemist. But if I know the size of my matrix and know it won't ever change, I think vectors of vectors will be much easier to visualize for both myself as a developer and for the users. The program takes (static) images as input and outputs some data about it. I'd rather have the user build a 2D vector of vectors than them having to learn about the 1D approach. Do you agree?

Comment: @user3076399: I'd rather have a class with `Matrix m(20,20);` and something like `m[0][0] = 1.0;` or `m(0, 0) = 1.0;` Because safely using the vector of vectors requires size/bounds checks for every sub-vector etc.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Every subvector will always be the same length, since the matrix is square.

Comment: Write a matrix class (or find an existing one). There's no excuse passing around C-style raw pointers like that, when writing C++ today.

Comment: @user3076399: Yeah but you'l have to check/assert it anyway - even if it should be properly sized you locally don't get any guarantee other than checking. If you have a class that provides that guarantee you can avoid to check every row.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`delete` can be called on a pointer even if it's passed as a `const &` or even declared `const` because the pointer is not going to be changed.

There is also no way to prevent someone from doing

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)your_precious_data_pointer;
*p = 42;
```

Get over it.

Const correctness was designed to detect accidental mistakes, not for preventing intentional actions by programmers. It's not about security.

It can even be debated if it's a good tool for preventing accidental mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you shouldn't use `new`, `delete` and raw owning pointers anyway, and certainly not `delete` arbitrary pointers.

If that isn't enough to switch to smart pointers and containers... You are actually triggering undefined behaviour by `delete`ing something which has visibly been allocated with `new[]`. That's another mistake to look out for with raw owning pointers.

On a side note, this is not a 2D array, but an array of pointers.

Comment: Why not? What should I use instead?

Comment: @juanchopanza it is. I'm giving myself the leeway not to type out "pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to the first element of more arrays of `double`s".

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, but we can't even know it is a pointer to the first element of an array. As far as the function is concerned, the parameter is a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza trust in the caller, so that `for`-loop doesn't just shoot off the end of the array into UB land. Raw pointers are all about trust after all.

Comment: @user3076399 you should have a look at `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe if OP understands that pointers are not arrays and pointers to pointers are not matrices, they'll understand why they can't get the desired "immutability".

Comment: @juanchopanza to be fair I don't see how that is relevant. A true dynamically allocated 2D array can be `delete[]`d all the same, be it `const` or not. That's just how `delete` works.