# 2d array and 1d array storage comparison?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

I have an issue understanding some things about arrays in C++.

If I have array with 3 rows and 4 colomns and I create them as 1d array and accessing each row data by looping through the array by 4 each time . does this way save me time in comparison with 2d approach that take much more allocation.

so instead of this:

```
int **array = new int * [3];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array[i] = new int [4];
}
```

I make this :

```
int *array = new int [3 * 4];
```

and I access each row data this way : rows = 3 , colomns = 4 :

```
for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < (3 * 4); j++) {
        cout << "row : << i << " , 4: " array[i * j];
    }
}
```

1. does this way save time for my program better than 2d or no?
2. Is it a bad approach or a good approach writhing my 2d array in 1d array like I what did?

**NOTE :**

My array will not be dynamic, the size of my array will be know before creating it, I will use it in my neural network project. and my concerns and focus are on speed.

Comment: access should be `array[colomns * i + j]` (or `array[rows * j + i]`)...

Comment: check my edits ? @Jarod42

Comment: You will have better cache with 1d array, but if size is known at compile time, you may directly do `int array[3][4];`.

Comment: you mean instead of the variables I put the known numbers ? check my edits @Jarod42

Comment: I meant you misuse the 1D array (even it is a good way).

Comment: why I misuse it tell me please ?

Comment: As I said, indexing should not be `[i * j]` (see first comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a Matrix class as follow:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class Matrix
{
public:
    const T& get(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const { return data[i][j]; }
    T& get(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return data[i][j]; }
private:
    T data[R][C] = {};
};
```

`data` would be contiguous, and offset computation will be done by compiler.

Usage would be something like:

```
 Matrix<int, 3, 4> mat;

 mat.get(1, 2) = 42;
```

Comment: do i need to create this template class for using as dynamic ? Note my size is known before compiling

Comment: and I i make it on heap ?

Answer (score 0):

If your array is not dynamic then there is no difference. Both will be laid out contiguously in memory.

If your array is dynamic then [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260533/7574136).

Comment: nono I will not use it as dynamic I know my size before compling . so In this case both are the same space and performance right ?