# Failing to change values of a pointer matrix

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I am having problems with dynamically changing matrix values using pointer.

I have these global declarations :

```
int row, col = 0;
float** matrixP;
float** matrixT;
float** matrixP_;
```

Then I have a function to take inputs from the user to populate **Any Matrix I want** :

```
void TakeInput(float** matrix, float row, float col) {

// Initializing the number of rows for the matrix
matrix = new float*[row];

// Initializing the number of columns in a row for the matrix
for (int index = 0; index < row; ++index)
    matrix[index] = new float[col];

// Populate the matrix with data
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < col; colIndex++) {
        cout << "Enter the" << rowIndex + 1 << "*" << colIndex + 1 << "entry";
        cin >> matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
    }
}

// Showing the matrix data
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < col; colIndex++) {
        cout << matrix[rowIndex][colIndex] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Then I have the main function **where I am taking inputs and just trying to show matrixP** :

```
int main() {
// Take the first point input
cout << "Enter the row and column for your points matrix" << endl;
cout << "Enter the number of rows : "; cin >> row;
cout << "Enter the number of columns : "; cin >> col;

TakeInput(matrixP, row, col);
cout << "=============================================================" << endl;
// =============================================================

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < col; colIndex++) {
        cout << matrixP[rowIndex][colIndex] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Now I am having problem in this part :

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < col; colIndex++) {
        cout << matrixP[rowIndex][colIndex] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And I got :

```
// matrixP is throwing access violation error.
```

Please need a helping hand here to point me out what i am doing wrong here.
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Simplify, simplify, simplify. And if you can't, [make a wrapper class to hide the nastiness.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op)

Comment: [Have a read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster).

Comment: guys come on, i am not trying to optimize my code here, i am trying to find what i am doing wrong with my messy code. I can use class, i can use many other approaches to simplify my things, but i am here to find out what i am doing wrong here logically.

Comment: I'm not even bothering with optimizing at this point. That's a bonus. My point is it's much easier create, manage, and pass around a `matrix` that contains even a `float **` than it is a naked `float **`. For example, `TakeInput` becomes `matrix TakeInput(int row, int col)`. All of the pointer craziness is packaged in `matrix` where you only need to get it right once.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error is you are passing the matrix as 
"pass by value" not pass by "reference", so replace your code with this

```
void TakeInput(float** &matrix, int row, int col)
```

also row and col should be **integers.**

Comment: Slight nag: `int` allows the caller to provide negative numbers, and negative array dimensions are... bad. An unsigned integer like `size_t` would be slightly safer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you pass matrixP to TakeInput by value, i.e. you edit copy of it in TakeInput. Do this instead.

```
void TakeInput(float*** matrix, float row, float col) {
//use (*matrix) instead
//...
}


TakeInput(&matrixP, row, col);
```

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/

Pointers are no different from usual ints on that matter.

EDIT:

```
void TakeInput(float** &matrix, float row, float col) {

// Initializing the number of rows for the matrix
matrix = new float*[row];

// Initializing the number of columns in a row for the matrix
for (int index = 0; index < row; ++index)
    matrix[index] = new float[col];

// Populate the matrix with data
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < col; colIndex++) {
        cout << "Enter the" << rowIndex + 1 << "*" << colIndex + 1 <<         "entry";
        cin >> matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this (float*** ) mean here ? if i do that I am getting errors on accessing the matrixP as in the above with for loops. can you explain it a little bit more here. if i don't do that I am getting error : argument of type "float ***" is incompatible with parameter of type "float **"

Comment: `float***` is a pointer to `float**`. You can pass a value by reference by passing pointers around if you need to change the value inside a function. But what if you need to pass a pointer by reference? Well, one way to do that is pass a pointer to the pointer so you can change the value of the pointer. A slightly better way to do this is with a reference to a `float**`: `float **& matrix`. Among other things this makes it much harder to pass a NULL pointer

Comment: Pointer to pointer to pointer, simple as that. If it is C++ not C then you could change it to the pass-by-reference: `void TakeInput(float** &matrix, float row, float col) {`. Then rest of your code is unchanged.

Comment: Okay I understand that, now how will i initialize it as i was trying to initialize above : `matrix = new float*[row];`

Comment: Almost same thing, just change function declaration from pass-by-value to pass by reference by adding ampersand (&). See my updated answer.

Comment: Besides, generally better practice would be to return this pointer to allocated memory from TakeInput, these "output" arguments are hard to read. Even if you really "need" them, returning a struct could be better solution. And as for in-memory matrices software I've seen (i.e. numpy) doesn't do it like that  You can just have single, regular pointer  `float *matrix = new float[N*M]`, and just refer to it as matrix[x*N +y]. This is faster when doing computation, because single chunk of memory can be cached at once, and is easier to work with.