# Why transposing this std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > is so slow?

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have a 1000-lines file of about 400MB representing some numeric data represented as string.
I want to transpose the data in order to have only 1000 strings per line, (so that I can open it and plot it fast with pandas).

I imported the whole file in a vector of vector of string that I want to transpose (and eventually I want to write back to file).

I use two nested loops to go through the 2d structure and I write it into some std::ofstream. It is very long.
Then I tried to focus on the transposition and I wrote the following code :

```
//Read 400MB file, 90K strings per line and 1K lines, and store it into
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> mData;

// ... 
// IO the file and populate mData with raw data 
// ...

//All rows have same number of string
size_t nbRows = mData.size();
size_t nbCols = mData[0].size();

std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > transposedData(nbCols);
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < nbCols  ; ++i)
{
    transposedData[i].resize(nbRows);
    for(size_t j = 0 ; j < nbRows ; ++j)
    {
        transposedData[i][j] = doc.mData[j][i];
    }
}
```

I thought a few seconds would be sufficient, but it takes several minutes.
Also, I am trying with different input dimensions (only 3 lines and much more strings per line, for a same file size of 400MB) and it's much faster.

EDIT 1

On people advice, I performed the profiling using callgrind.
I got this message during the process : 
... brk segment overflow in thread #1 : can't grow to ...

I analysed the result and summarize it here:
25 % is spent in operator= of basic_string
21 % is spent in construction of basic_string (with only 3% of time in new)
14 % is spent in operator()[] on the outside vector
11 % in spent in operator()[] on the inside vector

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you profile the code? I'm pretty sure the bottleneck are input and output.

Comment: Are the strings long or short? If they are long and you are not going to reuse mData, you could move the strings instead of copying them.

Comment: On Linux, you can use callgrind to profile the code

Comment: @dyukha Hi, in the code version I wrote here, there is no IO anymore.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Unfortunately the strings are very short, usually 3 char only.

Comment: Well, there is IO in your actual code, right? Did you verify already that it's not IO which uses most of the time?

Comment: @dyukha Yes I did, this is actually why I wanted to decouple the transposition task and the IO task. I admit I still need to import the data, (but I have checked this is not the bottleneck), but I am not writting anymore for the moment.

Comment: Why are you resizing in the loop?   You could easily get the vectors of right size, in both dimensions, by constructing `transposedData` sensibly.   You could also speed things up by using reference variables, rather than using `operator[]()` repeatedly with the same argument.

Comment: Note: Have a look at this question: [1D or 2D array, what's faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster) about vector of vector constructs and why you should use a one dimensional approch (with pre-allocation).

Comment: Because this is too much for the single CPU core. It seems like it is time to add `#pragma omp parallel for`  just before `for(size_t i = 0 ; i < nbCols  ; ++i)` and `-fopenmp` to compiler and linker, and then check how it is going after this change.

Comment: If you want to get the job done, you should not have been writing the program at all. Load the file into pandas and transpose the dataframe. If you want to learn C++ stuff that's another story.

Comment: Do you really need to copy all the strings?  If you don't need the original `mData` afterward, you could move-construct the `transposedData` values.  Alternatively, if you do need them, but they outlive `transposedData`, you could change the result to contain `std::string_view` objects instead.

Comment: You ought to create a [mcve].  That should be easy enough: add a `main()` and the required `#include` directives, and replace the "IO" comment with something to populate `mData` with test values.

Comment: I strongly suspect you are running a non-optimised build.

Comment: @n.m. I tried with pandas read_csv but it did not work because there are too many columns.

Comment: @Toby Speight Yes, then we would have realized immediately that there is no problem with this code and that the problem comes from my environment (here, memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough available memory on my machine to perform this task (see below).
Splitting my data in three parts, I solved the task in a few seconds.
Here is the output of a code scrutinizing memory :

> ```
> free ram 2.5GB  
> IO populating mData with raw data  
> free ram 0.2GB  
> Empty string capacity : 15 bytes  
> Intending to allocate 1.4 GB  
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  
>   what() : std::bad_alloc  
> Aborted
> ```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24213996)

Comment: I am satisfied with this solution so I edited my answer so that it looks like a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all before making any claim on the reason why a piece of code is slow you should really measure its performance on your machine and then with data at hand deduce *why*.

That said I am quite confident in this case in saying that the problem might reside in the fact that you are allocating `90k` vectors of string each of them of size `1k`. As you know memory allocation is costly, and it might explain your performance penalty.

The following is how you could implement your code using  only a `1D` array allocated upfront.

```
size_t nbRows = mData.size();
size_t nbCols = mData[0].size();

auto get_idx = [](const int i, const int nr, const int j)
{
    return i*nr+j;
};

std::vector<std::string> transposedData(nbCols*nbRows);  
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < nbCols  ; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0 ; j < nbRows ; ++j)
    {
        const int idx = get_idx(j, nbCols,i);
        transposedData[idx] = std::move(mData[j][i]);
    }
}

for(size_t i = 0 ; i < nbCols  ; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0 ; j < nbRows ; ++j)
    {
        const int idx = get_idx(j, nbCols,i);
        cout<<transposedData[idx]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

---

I would like to stress it again: profile your code. Try out software like `valgrind --tool= callgrind` or [`gprof`](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/gprof.html) allowing you to profile and visualize performance data about your app.

Comment: Thank you, actually it appears to be too much memory... "terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc".

Answer (score 1):

The program has redundancies on several levels.

The obvious one is that you don't need to transpose the vector in order to transpose the file.

```
vector<vector<string> originalData;
// read the file to originalData

for(size_t i = 0 ; i < nbCols  ; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0 ; j < nbRows ; ++j)
    {
        cout << originalData[j][i] << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Assuming you do need to produce a transposed vector for some reason, one way to write the transpose loop would be

```
vector<vector<string>> transposedData (nbCols);
for (size_t j = 0; j < nbCols; ++j)
{
    transposedData[j].reserve(nrows);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbRows; ++i) 
    {
        transposedData[j].emplace_back(originalData[i][j]);
        // if keeping original veector is not needed ...
        // transposedData[j].emplace_back(std::move(originalData[i][j]));
    }
}
```

On my (fairly beefy) machine it takes about 6-7 seconds to transpose a 1000x90000 matrix of 3-character strings. This is not particularly impressive, if you don't need to transpose multi-million-element matrices 24 hours a day, it does what you need without too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The penalty may come from the fact you're overusing resize on your for loop.

As per the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) :

> **Complexity**
>
> Linear in the difference between the current size and count. Additional complexity possible due to reallocation if capacity is less than count

Memory allocation costs a lot, so you may want to avoid overdoing it.

As pointed by others, upfront allocation would be an interesting approach to avoid recreating (resizing) your vector every time.