4D array allocation issue
I am trying various ways to code a 4D array (a stack of N x 2D x RGB images) hoping to find a good enough implementation that will let me efficiently retrieve columns of RGB pixels from that stack (ie. in Z direction). I understand the contiguous buffer is probably the way to go but I thought I'd test various alternatives.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the nested loops approach below? It allocates an order of magnitude more memory than the contiguous buffer and I don't understand why...
//allocate 4D array

    unsigned char**** Buff = new unsigned char*** [NumImages];

    for (unsigned int N = 0; N < NumImages; N++) {
        Buff[N] = new unsigned char** [ImageWidth];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ImageWidth; i++) {
            Buff[N][i] = new unsigned char* [ImageHeight];
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < ImageHeight; j++)
                Buff[N][i][j] = new unsigned char[ColorChannels];
        }
    }

Alternative is contiguous buffer:
contingousMemoryBlock = new unsigned char[NumImages * ImageWidth * ImageHeight * ColorChannels];

I tried both codes above and they don't allocate the same amount of memory.
[Edit] clarification of the question
Here is an example of values used
Channels = 1;
ImageWidth = 1000;
ImageHeight = 1000;
NumImages = 100;

I use the diagnostic tool from VS2019 to see how much total memory is allocated by the process, which clearly is not ideal as it encompasses many other overheads I imagine.
In Debug Mode, the nested loops code allocates 7GB, in release mode 2.7GB, which in both cases are way over the expected 100MB.
As for the contiguous code, in both Debug and Release it allocates 105MB which is very close to the theoretical 100MB.
So ok, leaving the nested loops approach, can I ask for further guidance on the best approach? By "best" I mean reasonably fast but also simple to code and scan through (I have limited C++ skills).
This thread (example of a 3D array) suggests using an iterator:
template <class Type>
class Matrix
{

  private:

    // size of matrix
    int Nx_ = 0;
    int Ny_ = 0;
    int Nz_ = 0;

    // matrix
    Type*** A3_;

  public:

    // constructor
    Matrix(int Nx, int Ny, int Nz)
    {

      Nx_ = Nx; 
      Ny_ = Ny;
      Nz_ = Nz;

      A3_ = new Type**[Nx];

      for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
      {

        A3_[i] = new Type*[Ny];
        for (int j = 0; j < Ny; j++)
        {
          A3_[i][j] = new Type[Nz];
        }

      }

    }
};

//Iterator
for (int k=0; k < K; ++k) {
    for (int j=0; j < J; ++j) {
        for (Type* it = get_iterator(i,j); it != get_iterator(i,j+1); ++it) {
             auto x = *it;
             // ...
        }
    }
}

while this other thread suggests using an array of pointers pointing to the contiguous buffer but I have no idea how to port it to 4D:
int main() {

    // variable nr of rows/columns:
    int rows = 2;
    int columns = 5;

    // allocate continuous block of memory
    char *contingousMemoryBlock = new char[rows*columns];

    // for demonstration purpose, fill in some content
    for (int i=0; i<rows*columns; i++) {
        contingousMemoryBlock[i] = '0' + i;
    }

    // make an array of pointers as a 2d-"view" of the memory block:
    char **arr2d= new char*[rows];
    for (int r=0; r<rows;r++) {
        arr2d[r] = contingousMemoryBlock + r*columns;
    }

    // access the continuous memory block as a 2d-array:
    for (int r=0; r<rows; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<columns; c++) {
            cout << arr2d[r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

Finally I have seen several threads suggesting using the vector type which allocates a contiguous large buffer while having memory management advantages AND while letting you retrieving a pointer to the allocated contiguous buffer for efficient scanning. That sounds good but how do I then retrieve efficiently my columns of RGB pixels...?
[Edit2] Based on the comments
Based on the comments I wanted to investigate std:mdspan but turns out it is not supported by my outdated VS2019. So I turned to Boost multi_array which seems to do the job. Thank you all

How do you check how much memory each of them allocates?

"...I  tried both codes above and they don't allocate the same amount of memory..." The 1st approach will allocate more memory because of all the pointers as it needs the same amount of data for the images and additional memory for the pointers.

In the first version there are many additional pointers that require allocation. In any case - I think the contiguous buffer approach (and managing the indices "manually") is a far better approach.

BTW, avoid raw owning pointer, use intermediate class and vector/array, something like struct Color {char r, g, b, a}; struct Image {std::vector<std::vector<Color>> pixels; /*or flatten version*/}; std::vector<Image>allImages;

Are you absolutely sure you don't need simple struct Color{ char r, g, b; };, struct Image{int w, h; std::vector<Color> pixels;}; and then store it in the container? Obviously retrieving a column of "R"s in position [x,y] requires iterating over your Images, so it's slow, but maybe not slow enough to bother you.

"It allocates an order of magnitude more memory" -- That seems like a lot, but the amount of overhead depends on the sizes involved. (Over the course of all iterations, the line Buff[N][i][j] = new unsigned char[ColorChannels]; allocates the same number of characters as the contiguous buffer, so the other allocations are your overhead.) Could you add some concrete data, including the values of NumImages, ImageWidth, ImageHeight, and ColorChannels along with the exact amount of memory allocated for each method?

Most implementations over allocate for small objects. For example you might find that when you're trying to allocate 3 bytes for 3 colour channels you allocate maybe even 24 bytes! Why. There's almost certainly a hidden "housekeeping" overhead to each allocation and often the memory manager is optimised and has a minimum allocation size and always allocates at least that - no matter what you asked for!

new expressions often over-allocate for various reasons (e.g. based on what strategies your standard library uses to handle allocation and reallocation) in practice.   Rather than using operator new, I'd consider using std::vector (assuming all of your dimensions aren't known until run time).   Done properly, that reduces a number of risks of new expressions - such as making it harder to release more than once (undefined behaviour) and reducing chances of memory leaks.

I'd also be surprised if colorChannels is a large value  (e.g. 24 bit colour can be represented by a triplet of 8-bit unsigned bytes).  Which suggests, rather than an array (dynamically allocated or not), you can use a struct to represent individual colours (like the struct Color mention by pptaszni)

The first stores NumImages * ImageWidth * ImageHeight pointers. Assuming 64-bit pointers, it will need eight times as much memory as the contiguous case.

In general write a wrapper class (e.g an Image class) and allocate a 1D std::vector (for contiguous ordering in memory!) then do the offset calculations yourself.  Or use C++23's std::mdspan. Really really try to avoid code like this : unsigned char**** Buff = new unsigned char*** [NumImages]; your just setting youself up for all kind of memory managment problems.

You can find a thread discussing 1D vs n/3-D approaches (in terms of speed but also with examples) here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster

Lots of good comments and tips, thank you. Next I will investigate the std::vector approach as well as the std::mdspan approach

If you want to allocate all your images in a contiguous manner, then you already have your code:
unsigned char* contingousMemoryBlock = new unsigned char[NumImages * ImageWidth * ImageHeight * ColorChannels];

This will be fast but less than ideal, because it's confusing to index this 4-D array, represented by a plain pointer.
First of all, note that you don't need the images to be contiguous. The requirement of contiguous memory is only relevant for a single image (because most image processing implementations require it for speed). This will make it possible to regard your data structure as an array of 3-D buffers. Assuming each 3-D buffer is represented by a pointer:
#include <vector>
...

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char*> ListOfImages;
    for (unsigned int N = 0; N < NumImages; N++) {
        ListOfImages.push_back(new unsigned char[ImageWidth * ImageHeight * ColorChannels]);
    }

    // to access a specific pixel:
    // ListOfImages[image_idx][(y * ImageWidth + x) * ColorChannels + ch]

    // Don't forget to deallocate
    for (unsigned char* image_buffer: ListOfImages) {
        delete[] image_buffer;
    }
}

Note the access comment above. This is important detail: you don't access your data structure as a 4-D array. Rather than that, you must use plain 1-D indexing to access individual images and a 3-D raster addressing formula to access pixels inside each image.
You might want to invent a struct or class to hold your buffer pointer. Then, if you do it right, delete[] at the end will be called automatically. I don't want to show how to do that; I think it's out of scope here.

When you allocate a contiguous buffer, you use a single pointer and one large block of memory.
However, when you manually allocate a multi-dimensional array, you end up with multiple pointers pointing to more pointers, each leading to small blocks of memory. Each pointer takes up 8 bytes, and every dynamically allocated memory block incurs an additional overhead of more than 8 bytes.
Since the memory is not contiguous, your array access speed will be extremely slow.
Avoid using pointer arrays just to access elements like Buff[i][x][y][ColorChannel]. Furthermore, non-contiguous buffers are completely incompatible with most image processing functions.
Each image requires its own contiguous buffer, though it doesn’t mean all images need to share a single large buffer.
Also, the last dimension of your array is unnecessary; it’s better to use a structure. On Windows, this could be RGBQUAD or RGBTRIPLE.
